# Floating point conversion

Tags: python

How can I  create a floating point decimal from the two variables who are integers

```
i=1
j=9
```

is there anyway to combine these two and get the floating point decimal 1.9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```
floatingpoint=float(str(i)+'.'+str(j))
```

**Edit**:

```
>>> float('%d.%d' % (i,j))
1.9
```

Comment: Please use string placeholders for this: `floatingpoint = float('%s.%s' % (i, j))`

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
>>> i = 1
>>> j = 9
>>> i + j / 10.0
1.8999999999999999
```

Answer (score 1):

Not [exactly](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues).

```
>>> float(1+9*0.11)
1.99
>>> 1+9 * 0.1
1.8999999999999999
```